# Issue with and without http and www

Tags: http

I notice on my website if I go to http domain I'm logged in but if I go to www domain I am not logged in. Is there something that causes this? Does it have to do with the htaccess? or can it be a number of things?

Comment: Does "logged in" means "authenticated" in your words?

Answer (score 2):

Your browser treats "www.example.com" and "example.com" as different hosts and therefore assigns different cookies. If you login at one host, your browser accepts that session. However, on the other host, there are other cookies and you are therefore not logged in.

You might want to redirect from the domain to your "www" subdomain (or vice versa).